# what the best rails way to do the following

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've rails 3 app which displays records from a DB into table. I want the same method to check if the admin controller is used and if so add edit delete options to the table items.

Example: logged in a none admin server/home/list_info

- Some info name address
- More info name address

Logged in as Admin sever/admin/list_info

- Some info name address Edit Delete
- More info name address Edit Delete

I've currently got two controllers and two view methods, the admin method is just a copy with the Edit Delete links on the end. 
This doesn't seem very DRY to me. What to people do in this situation ?

Many Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to have one set of controllers/views and simply see if the current user is an admin. If yes, show the edit/delete links.

Typically, you could use Devise for authentication and CanCan for authorization.

Devise provides a current_user object, so if you implement an `admin?` method you could use something like

```
<%= link_to_if current_user.admin?, 'Delete', ... %>
```

Note: the above uses only Devise, not CanCan.

Comment: ok thanks , I was more after an answer for generating the html table. depending on user or admin , within the same method

Comment: You can have the same method to generate the table based on user or admin: simply have the code above in one of the cell's table (where you'd put the link in the admin view)